# How to pass List<string> model property to view javascript array variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel with a property

```
public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
```

How do I pass the values of the list to an array variable?

Currently have this javascript code in my view, but it has error on the answers array inside the foreach loop.

*The name answers does not exists in the current context.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var answers = [];
    @foreach(string answer in Model.Answers)
    {
        var ans = @answer;
        answers.push(ans);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Because `@foreach` is razor code (parsed on the server before its sent to the browser) and `var answers` is a javascript variable - it does not even exist at that point. Use `var answers = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Answers))`

Comment: this worked StephenMuecke just add the '@' before the html helper "@var answers = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Answers))"

Comment: you should add this as an answer. Id be happy to choose it.

Comment: Oops - that was a typo - I'll see if a can find a suitable dupe first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serializing Json. Use it religiously ! Then think about the cleanest way to get the json to the client. Usually this is a separate api call. We retrofitted web api to our server-rendered application so we don't even need to worry about invoking Json.net. We just return C# objects and web api converts them. (not new technology !) You really shouldn't be doing this in a razor template.

Comment: OP is not asking about how to _get the json to the client_

Comment: Can't help myself.